# Specific Portion of the Screen Dedicated to SurfaceView

Tags: android

What I wanted to achieve is this:

[image]

I wanted to have a specific portion of the screen to be my `SurfaceView`. I will use this `SurfaceView` for some animations. But I wanted to include some `Views` like `TextView` and `RadioButtonGroup` beside my `SurfaceView`.

So my question is, is this possible? I looking for sample android source code about 'animating sprites', but I couldn't find any activity that incorporates both `TextViews` and `SurfaceView`. All are extending `SurfaceView`. If this is possible, how do I do it? Do you have sample source codes that I can try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this i am not extending surfaceview.

```
    public class Preview_can_work extends Activity {
        private SurfaceView surface_view;  
        SurfaceHolder.Callback sh_ob = null;
        SurfaceHolder surface_holder        = null;
        SurfaceHolder.Callback sh_callback  = null;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

            surface_view = new SurfaceView(getApplicationContext());
            addContentView(surface_view, new LayoutParams(50, 50));

            if (surface_holder == null) {
                surface_holder = surface_view.getHolder();
            }

            sh_callback = my_callback();  // CREATING CALLBACK FOR YOUR SURFACE.
            surface_holder.addCallback(sh_callback);
        }

        // THIS FUNCTION RETURNS CALLBACK OBJECT FOR SURFACEVIEW.
            SurfaceHolder.Callback my_callback() {      
                SurfaceHolder.Callback ob1 = new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {

                    @Override
                    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
                            int height) {
                    }
                };
                return ob1;
        }

    }
```

now you can simply add any textview or button on your layout it should work.

Note:- I am creating surface dynamically. In your case what you can do is you can create everything in xml file. Instead of creating surfaceview create video view.

SurfaceView surface_view = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.video_view_id);

if you are fetch view by id from your layout then you have to remove some line from code. which are:

```
            surface_view = new SurfaceView(getApplicationContext());
            addContentView(surface_view, new LayoutParams(50, 50));
```

Hope it will help you...

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible but you might need to present a little more information.  If you want some simple animation to run next to the textview then you don't even need a surfaceview.  Just create an imageview and run an animation on it ([here is a tutorial](http://androiddev101.com/2012/02/22/episode-3-animation-4-life/) I created for the very topic)

TextView and its kin DO NOT derive from Surfaceview they derive from the View class.  Once again if you want to perform simple animations I don't think you will need a surfaceview.  If you want to do more dynamic complex things then there is [also a tutorial](http://androiddev101.com/2012/03/18/episode-4-how-to-make-an-android-game/) on my development blog on how to utilize a SurfaceView for a game.  If that is more your flavor then you can create a custom surface view and then just tie it into your layout with the size dimensions you want.